# Can't find a working selector on drop down menu while using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, selector, puppeteer

I'm creating an automated script with puppeteer and I'm running across a problem of trying to find a selector that could be understood. I have tried many different options but gotten no luck. 
Note:Don't worry its a dummy account so nothing important is on it.

I tried using

```
const myacc = '.li.member-nav-item.d-sm-ib.va-sm-m > button';
```

and bunch of others but still getting selector error

Code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var emailVal = 'kellybrando23434@gmail.com';

var passwordVal = 'd34gfA@4dfW';

const AcceptCookies = '#cookie-settings-layout > div > div > div > div.ncss-row.mt5-sm.mb7-sm > div:nth-child(2) > button';

const loginBtn = 'li.member-nav-item.d-sm-ib.va-sm-m > button';

const email = 'input[type="email"]';

const password = 'input[type="password"]';

const logsubmit = '.loginSubmit.nike-unite-component > input[type="button"]';

const myacc = '.li.member-nav-item.d-sm-ib.va-sm-m > button'; //this line contains error

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, slowMo: 150});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 })
    await page.goto('https://www.nike.com/launch/');        const AcceptCookies = '#cookie-settings-layout > div > div > div > div.ncss-row.mt5-sm.mb7-sm > div:nth-child(2) > button';         await page.click(loginBtn);
    console.log("Login Button Clicked...");

    await page.waitFor(5000);

    console.log("email: " + emailVal);
    await page.type(email, emailVal);
    console.log("entered email");

    await page.type(password, passwordVal);

    console.log("waiting 0.5s");
    await page.waitFor(500);
    console.log("waiting done");

    await page.click(logsubmit);
    console.log("submitted");       await page.waitFor(10000);      await page.click(myacc);    await page.waitFor(10000);

    await browser.close();  })();
```

I'm trying to get the correct selector - "const myacc=..."- to click account profile as shown in the picture (highlighted section) but instead I'm getting a selector error ("Error:No node found for selector:...."). How would you find it in this situation as their is no id?

**Before Picture**

[image: Before Picture]

**After Picture**

[image]

Comment: Never share you email id and password in public, if that is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are almost all of the elements contains a unique attribute for testing `data-qa`. I would recommend using it for testing, so replace all your selectors with it.

Here is the example for the 'my account' selector:

```
const myAcc = '[data-qa="user-name"]';
```

Also, you may not see that the selector was clicked due to screen size, so you will need to maximize screen size.

Comment: That seemed to have worked. Thanks